Any way to get UI order of workspaces using Python?
Workspaces while being displayed in UI have different order comparing to while being stored in bpy.data.

For example, UI order is ["Workspace 2", "Workspace 3", "Workspace 1"]:



But in in bpy.data.workspaces these workspaces are ordered alphabetically:



It seems like there is no direct way of retrieving UI order...
But what about workarounds?
➤ Is there any workaround to retrieve the UI order of workspaces?


maybe the patch could be accepted if the prop was set as readonly (?). But I guess the workaround is needed for the current version of blender?

@lemon  — >>"I guess the workaround is needed for the current version of blender?">> — Correct, Blender 4.3.2 still doesn't have a direct way of retrieving this info. Though since mentioned Devtalk.Blender topic is 3 years old - there are chances that in last three years someone finally found a workaround – that's why I'm asking.
